Spring boot - admin login with "Bad credentials" error
I am creating a basic Spring boot application with only a "hello" page. Then I set a login form.
What I want:
I want to login to my application.
Problem:
Run my application. From the debug log, I see "Using generated security password: 7f051244-35fc-4b3e-8294-fa332462835d (Just 1 of the security password because it is different every time I restart the system)". Springboot's default username is "user". I enter these 2 information to login. Then I see "Bad credentials" in the browser. Error display in debug log is: "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt".
The below is code:
WebSecurityConfig.java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URLS = {
            "/hello",
    };

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests

                        .requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URLS).permitAll()
                );

        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

}

HelloController.java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/api/hello")
    public String hello(Principal principal) {
        return "Hello " +principal.getName() + ".";
    }
}

Since the security password is generated by the system, I think it should be alright for admin login. But the strange thing is, it fails.
I googled the BCrypt error. Since the password isn't generated by me, similar error in google history occurs only when login as USER instead of ADMIN, I think it should not be the root cause.
Please give me a helping hand. Thanks!

if you get the default password in the logs during startup means that your security config is not picked up during startup scan but since you have posted extremely little code, it is impossible to help you more, good luck
